# Is it possible to delete user-defined cost allocation tags in the AWS Billing console?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a number of unused user-defined cost allocation that show up under `AWS Billing -> Cost allocation tags -> User-defined cost allocation tags` in the AWS console. I was wondering if it's possible to delete these tags?

I don't have a lot of tags as you can see from the provided screenshot; I'm just trying to reduce clutter as much as possible moving forward.

[image: Cost allocation tags in AWS Console]

Answer (score -1):

These are tags in AWS so if you delete them in the Tag Manager they will not show up here. Source, https://handbook.vantage.sh/aws/concepts/tags/

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).